# Spring app consumes all CPU and then crashes

Tags: java, spring, garbage-collection

I have a `Spring` application that has been recently moved from test to production environment. CPU usage is %2-3 most of the time. But sometimes (1 or 2 times per day) it suddenly peaks up to %400 (there are 4 cpus) and then my app crashes. I could not observe any kind of anomalies (e.g. extra traffic) when the problem occurred.

Some information about my app is,

- It has some REST endpoints that are called by android clients.
- It has 3 `ScheduledTask`s in one of the `Service`s. They make some `HttpUrlConnection`s.
- My traffic is not very huge, e.g. 300-400 requests per minute and it is mostly stable, i.e. no peaks are observed in network calls.
- CPU usage reaches a maximum value of %3 with this traffic, except the times that the problem occurs. Here is a visualization of the CPU utilization for the last 24 hours:
  [image]
- My server has 4 core cpu, 12 GB RAM and 300GB Full SSD disk. Linux version 4.4.0-93-generic (buildd@lgw01-03) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) )
- Memory settings: `-d64 -Xms6g -Xmx10g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`
- I used `sysstat` for logging. I am watching the cpu and ram usage not only for the whole system but also for my app only. I would like to note also that ram usage peaks up to max %60.
  [An example from CPU logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSZKp.png)
  **GC logs and Thread Dumps:** 
  I logged GC, and also Thread dumps (jstack) with 2 minutes interval. No difference was displayed normal time, before crash and at crash time.
- Logs between :  20:30 - 06:26
- Server crash down time: 06:26
- [GC Analysis](http://gceasy.io/my-gc-report.jsp?p=c2hhcmVkLzIwMTcvMTAvOS8tLWdjXzIwMTcxMDA5XzA3MzAubG9nLS0xNC0xNS0w)
- [Thread dumps](http://fastthread.io/my-thread-report.jsp?p=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)
      ( Thread dump 1 (05:40) .. Thread dump 14 (06:24) )
      ( Other Thread Dumps are before 05:40)
- GC analysis comment: "97.14% of the time it was due to Allocation Failure. But its time that 21:12:22 when 9 hours before crash."
- Last errors in log file

  - `2017-10-09 06:26:19.393 ERROR 5986 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] t.o.m.w.rest.errors.ExceptionTranslator  : An unexpected error occurred: I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is java.io.InterruptedIOException: XNIO000808: I/O operation was interrupted`
  - `2017-10-09 06:26:19.396 ERROR 5986 --- [ XNIO-2 task-25] io.undertow.request                      : UT005022: Exception generating error page /error`

I could not find the reason of the problem. Are there any suggestions? Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: With the error message `I/O operation was interrupted` my first guess would be, that my app is trying to read or write some file, but something interrupted it. Like, the file got moved/deleted while accessing it or something like that. Hard to tell without any code.

Comment: @Korashen An IO problem does not cause the CPU to be 400%. So the IO Exception is more likely to be a result rathen than being a reason... The project is very big, and the problem does not seem to be originated from a specific piece of code. Instead, it seems to be a GC problem.

Comment: Could be, could be not. I would also exclude an endless recursion, as it would cause a different type or error message and only one core of your CPU would run at 100%. Well, just to exclude it and have it written...

Comment: Hm, what is very suspicious is the extrem high size of your old gen space. Thumb rule is that not more than 10% of your objects will ever make it into the old gen. Some say 5%, others 15%, whatever, yours is above 50%. So an issue with cleaning stuff up is very likly. Question is, is it the GC, that is messing up, or do you keep to many references on your objects for too long?

Comment: And, not sure about the website you are using, but your GC report states a sum of 11.05 gb used memory, while having the XMX on 10G. Maybe a rounding issue in the report, maybe an important hint. Wild Guess: As you are already using more than specified in the XMX, the VM says simply no to an allocation request. Which is the IO Exception you see. The VM will simply not give you any more bits and bytes.

Comment: @Korashen 11.05gb of which 1.05gb are metaspace, which is not part of heap and xmx only speciefies heap size, so everthing is fine there...

Comment: @Jonathan If I get that right (which I might don't), the heap would be at 10G, so it would be at it's max. Running at the limit does not sound fine to me. But I'm no expert with the memory, still a lot of stuff I need to learn...

Comment: @Korashen the JVM will max out the memory against the OS. Garbage collection is most efficient if it runs seldom and is able to remove as many dead objects as possible. I've looked at the gc-easy logs and they look very fine. In this case, I would not assume a memory problem.

Comment: @Jonathan Ok, thanks for the explanation. Didn't knew the VM will max out against the OS. Something, the tools I use never showed, as it also was never that important. But still important to know!

Comment: To me your data looks inconclusive yet. I don't think, you are suffering from a memory problem. Your gc-logs seem quite fine to me. Have you considered using a profiler like YourKit or JProfiler to analyze the moment of the crash? They have both modes, in which they will trigger performance-snapshots at high cpu-usage. It would be the way to go for me at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the invaluable comments indicate, this problem does not originate from garbage collection. The reason is something totally different. It took about a week to figure it out, so I am writing it to here in case some other people face with the same problem.

First of all, I did not include in the question (since I did not consider it as important) that I used [JHipster](http://www.jhipster.tech/), which recently switched to `Undertow` as the application server.

After digging into the details, I observed that the threads that consume the CPU are `XNIO` threads. I have seen on a few sites that some people using application servers powered by `XNIO` also suffer from the same problem. Since `Undertow` uses `XNIO`, I changed from `Undertow` to `Tomcat`, and the problem is resolved.